# Animation looks fine when rendered as frames but pale when rendered as video :c

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video

I've made a little animation and rendered it, everything's fine.
But when I try to render it as a video instead of as frames, the resulting video looks very pale in color compared to the original frame :
[image: rendered frame / rendered animation]

Here are my render container / codec settings :

[image]

I am using the 'perceptually lossless' quality and it don't seems to be a problem with the quality.

I also use the default color space and I use the VSE to render the animation.

PS : I'm french, so my english may not be the best ^^'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is probably your playback software failing to decode the stream correctly. Turn off GPU acceleration and re-test.